# MongoDB: how to parse a string into correct date format

Tags: string, mongodb, date

I am wanting to parse a string that is currently in the following format:

```
MM/dd/YYYY hh:MM:ss
```

to the following format:

```
YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:ss
```

I am wanting to do this within a MongoDB query.

Comment: Please post some example documents. Also, what is the goal? Are you displaying the new format, or are you looking to modify the document?

Comment: Hoping to convert the modified string into a date type later in the query. Not wanting to change the document, long term. @KevinAdistambha

Comment: In this case, I think it's better to handle the date manipulation in the application code. Also, MongoDB provides date manipulation functions in relation to a document, instead of a general library of date manipulation, so you'll have to do it in the application anyway.